# Is nosein ta'am lifegam mutar only bedieved or even lechatchilah?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, food, issur-vheter

If a food is hot enough, it can give off its taste into the utensil it is touching. This is called *bli'os*.

If these bli'os are less than 24 hours old, they are called *nosein ta'am leshevach*, and could be problematic. (For instance, cooking milk in a pot that has absorbed meat.) If these bli'os are more than 24 hours old, they are called *nosein ta'am lefegam* and are subject to a machlokes Tannaim (see, for instance, AZ 67b and 75b-76a).

On AZ 65b, the Mishnah (as emended by the Gemara on the same amud), following the opinion that nosein ta'am lefegam is allowed, says that if wine used for idolatry (*yayin nesech*, forbidden even for non-eating benefit) fell on figs, if there is enough for the taste to be discernible, the figs are forbidden to be eaten. However, if it is nosein ta'am lefegam, it is permissible.

From the Mishnah's case of "if this happened...", can we infer that this is only in a bedieved case, that is, when the wine already spilled, if it's nosein ta'am lefegam it is permissible? Or is this ruling even lechatchilah - one may spill wine on the figs and eat them, if it is nosein ta'am lefegam?

For the record, we do pasken like the opinion that nosein ta'am lefegam is permissible (Rambam Ma'achalos Asuros 16:33, SA YD 134:9).

Comment: "If these bli'os are less than 24 hours old, they are called nosein ta'am leshevach, and could be problematic." That's not technically the definition of nosein ta'am leshevach. NTLSh means it improves the flavor, and NTLF means it hurts the flavor. What any particular flavor does after any number of hours is a local issue. Even a completely fresh flavor could end up being NTLF and (according to some, at least) even a week old flavor could be NTLSh.

Comment: @DoubleAA The Gemara on AZ 75b-76a would disagree with you on that.

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34603/759

Comment: Huh? What's to disagree with? These are just definitions.

Comment: @doubleaa Yes, that is indeed exactly what I'm asking. Thanks! (How do you find these questions?) As for disagreeing, all I'm saying is that the Gemara explicitly defines NTLF as a non-ben yomo and NTLS as a ben yomo.

Comment: I can check the Gemaras again, but I think they are just giving common cases. In [nearly] all cases, the flavors in a week old pot will hurt flavor of the dish, and in most cases the flavors in an hour old pot will improve flavor of the dish. It still depends what you actually choose to cook with what flavor. (For the curious, the case of a week old pot possibly improving flavor is if you cook asafoetida in it. The simple way of understanding that is asafoetida is so bad or strong, that any dilution is an improvement. Others hold that's only a Gezera Derabnan.)

Comment: @DoubleAA I'll save you the trouble: אמר רב חייא בריה דרב הונא לא אסרה תורה אלא קדירה בת יומא דלאו נותן טעם לפגם הוא מכאן ואילך לישתרי גזירה קדירה שאינה בת יומא משום קדירה בת יומא ואידך קדירה בת יומא נמי מפגם פגמה